# Select by attribute how to only select numbers in a string field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

Using a SQL experssion in the "Select by Attributes" table, how would I only select records 1, 4, 5, 8 and omit the rest `(I only want to select values that are entirely numbers)`? What I have right now is `SUBSTRING(address,1,1)<='9' AND SUBSTRING(address,1,1)<> ' '`, but it won't catch record 2(`1234 S Complex`).

[image]

Comment: You may try to look for question about  "regular expression" or "regex" as I think this is the tool for your use case (don't know it well enough to help you with it)

Comment: To clarify, you want to only select the records whose 'address' attribute value contains only numbers (no letters at all)?

Comment: Correct cmrROse, just numbers. I can't believe this has been this difficult.

Comment: Since you want to have ONLY numbers, one workaround is to create a separate column and use the field calculator (which can accept Python expressions in a codeblock). The expression .isdigit() would check all values, not just the starting character.

Comment: I suggest [editing your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/298045/edit) to include the storage format of your feature class: shapefile, file/personal geodatabase, DBMS, etc.

Comment: -1 because your question and comments contradict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

CAST(address AS INTEGER) >= 0

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you. How does this not select a value like '1234 S Complex'? I'm just curious as to how it works.

Comment: @GIS_GOD I suppose if the value contains anything other than numbers then it cannot be cast as an integer.